# How to convert audio in each directory by FFmpeg and batch script.

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

After a hard study, I have created a `batch` file:

```
for /R  D:\storytelling\MusicFiles %%a in (*.3gp) do ffmpeg -i %%a -y %%~na.mp3
```

However, it can't reach my goal since the scenario is a little different here:

Here is my directory structure:
[image]

I have several directories under a certain path:`D:\storytelling\MusicFiles\` and new directories could be created by another application. And I put `ffmpeg.exe` file in this path: `D:\storytelling\MusicFiles\`.

Also, In each directory, I have hundreds of `.3gp` files, and my target is to convert them to `.mp3` in the directory where they `used` to stay at. 

But this script

```
for /R  D:\storytelling\MusicFiles %%a in (*.3gp) do ffmpeg -i %%a -y %%~na.mp3
```

would convert every `.3gp` file in each directory to the path: `D:\storytelling\MusicFiles\`

It leads to:[image]

**But** I want the `publicUser_XXX.mp3` files are still in the directory `publicUser` and after conversion all the files remain in their original directory. The only change is that I got new a media copy with different media format like: [image]

Please help and give me some advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for /R  D:\storytelling\MusicFiles %%a in (*.3gp) do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -y "%%~dpna.mp3"
```

Comment: Great, it works!. May I ask you why don't you add quotation mark to like: "(*.3gpp)" and why did you add that to %%~dpna.mp3, what's the timing?
And... What does `%%~dpna` actually do?

Comment: Btw: Stackoverflow already provides a button to let you upload the image.

Comment: @Stallman - thanks  for replying - I found the upload button.

Comment: `%%~dpna` uses the `drive:\path\name` portion of the original name so it locates the target file on your drive.  You use double quotes on paths or filenames that will have spaces or & characters etc and can also be used on names and paths without spaces etc, so pretty much all the time to be robust.  They aren't needed in the filespec *.3gp.   If `D:\storytelling\MusicFiles` had a space or & then you would have to double quote that too.

Comment: So do you mean that I must add quotation marks as the file name contains `spaces` and `&`? And at other time, it depends on me? I think (*.3gpp) is also a file name, can I add quotation mark to it?

Comment: As you are about to post a question you can click a button, it allows to upload image from your computer and internet. Btw: Does "%%~na.mp3" means `new` a file, and its' file name is extracted from %%`a`? And as I add `dp`, those things combines to a new string.

Comment: It's always good practice to use "path\filename" because then you don't have to redesign the code later for long filenames.  (*.3gp) part of a for-in-do command will never need quotes.  There are many cases in batch files where exemptions-to-the-rule apply and learning them slowly as you need them is a good way.  In general always double quote "c:\folder\filename.ext"

Comment: %%~n is the part that applies the name part of the metavariable and the a is the suffix because you used %%a.  If you used %%B then it would be %%~nB (case sensitive).  See the `for /?` help on the last page for a list.